# Put image in subfig's subfloat caption

Tags: subfloats

I need to put an image "tinyimage" inside the caption of a subfloat of the subfig package.

Minimal *not* working example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[\includegraphics{tinyimage}]{\includegraphics{bigimage}}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So far I tried the following:

- put a \protect{} around the \includegraphics{} in the caption.
- store the \includegraphics{} in a \savebox and put \usebox in the caption.

The error I get is:

```
Argument of \sf@@@subfloat has an extra }. ...phics{tinyimage}]{\includegraphics{big image}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add all tree arguments of `\subfloat[][]{}` command:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \subfloat[][{\includegraphics{tinyimage}}]{\includegraphics{bigimage}}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that the second optional argument is `{\includegraphics{tinyimage}}`: extra `{...}` are necessary for optional argument of `\includegraphics{...}` command.

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that the first optional argument (if present) defines the entry in the list of figures.